# Settings and global variables in one place

Tags: python, configuration, yaml

I have a configuration (YAML) file used across related modules. I also have a few additional variables to be accessed globally in my modules. I want to have them at one place (an instance of a class in my implementation below but I am willing to change it).

This implementation (based on recommendations from the web and ChatGPT) is working as intended. I like that I can define the basic dictionary needed across all modules and then add additional items to the dictionary based on the particular module I'm calling by their relevant methods.

But there must be a better implementation. In particular, I don't like storing the database engine in a dictionary (as almost all other items have strings). And storing it as a separate instance variable seems to have one outlier. Another thing I don't like is the long name when using dictionary notation `config['parameter1']['parameter2']`.

What is a better way to handle this? Any help is appreciated.

```py
"""Module to setup configuration parameters (read from YAML + additional)"""

import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path

import dotenv
import sqlalchemy
import yaml

from . import utils

# project directory as basepath irrespective of Python script or Jupyter notebook
BASEPATH = utils.agnostic_path(Path().resolve())

dotenv.load_dotenv()
codify_env = os.getenv("CODIFY_ENV")
codify_client = os.getenv("CODIFY_CLIENT")


class CodifyConfig:
    """
    CodifyConfig
    """

    def __init__(self, path_config: Path = Path(BASEPATH, "config", "config.yml")):
        self.path_config = path_config
        self.config = self.load_config()
        self.setup_additional_params()

    def load_config(self):
        """Loads project wide YAML configuration file"""
        with open(self.path_config, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            config = yaml.safe_load(file)["client"][codify_client][codify_env]
        return config

    def setup_additional_params(self):
        """
        Adds parameters to config not in the YAML config file because
        initial YAML parameters are chosen based on some of these parameters
        """
        self.config["basepath"] = BASEPATH
        self.config["client"] = codify_client
        self.config["env"] = codify_env

    def setup_database(self, db: str = ""):
        """Create database engine"""
        db = db or self.config.get("database_url")
        self.config["engine"] = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db)

    def setup_logging(self, fn_log: str = "default.log") -> None:
        """Defaults and file name for logging"""
        path_log = Path(self.config["basepath"], "logs", fn_log)

        logging.basicConfig(
            filename=path_log,
            filemode="a",
            format="%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
            datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
            level=logging.INFO,
        )
```

Comment: Please note we have a fairly strict [policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Another thing I don't like is the long name when using dictionary notation `config['parameter1']['parameter2']`.

Consider using the
[glom](https://pypi.org/project/glom)
library, which was designed to address
exactly that concern.

---

## informative identifier

```
# project directory as basepath irrespective of Python script or Jupyter notebook
BASEPATH = utils.agnostic_path(Path().resolve())
```

Thank you for the comment, I find it helpful.

But I'm sad that you felt you needed a comment.
That is, `agnostic_path` seems to be an unhelpful identifier.
Ideally we wouldn't need to write a comment at all.

Maybe `utils.script_folder()` would be more self explanatory?
I often will add a `get_repo_top()` helper to my projects,
which does the equivalent of `$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

I feel your utility function should definitely
return `Path` rather than `str`.
It is more descriptive.
And it is easier / less visually intrusive to convert to str,
with `f"{folder}"`, than the other way 'round.

---

## clean import

```
dotenv.load_dotenv()
```

This is not terrible,
but I'd rather see it protected
by `if __name__ == '__main__':`
or run within some function.

I assume it will complain if the calling user lacks dot files.
A `$ python -m unittest` run should import
cleanly, without error, even if dot files are missing.
An import on a CI/CD host or container
should work smoothly, even if dot files are missing.

From its [section](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports)
you're telling me pretty clearly that `$ pip install dotenv`
is the way to obtain this library.
But I don't see that method in
[the source](https://github.com/pedroburon/dotenv/blob/master/dotenv/__init__.py).

---

## globals

```
codify_env = os.getenv("CODIFY_ENV")
codify_client = os.getenv("CODIFY_CLIENT")
```

These are *kind* *of* OK as module level symbols.
But maybe there's no need to clutter up that Public API namespace,
maybe we could defer the lookup until we need it?
Or do it within an `__init__` ctor?

As a followup to the "clean import" remarks above,
I *do* thank you for accepting `None` when env var is undefined.
Flip side of that is, when we actually use the value,
maybe `os.eviron["CODIFY_ENV"]` would offer a clearer
diagnostic in the event someone forgot to set it?

---

## unhelpful docstring

```
    """
    CodifyConfig
    """
```

Please delete.

Or write an English sentence describing the responsibility of this class.
That will be an aid to future maintainers, who will pass up the
temptation to add `kitchen_sink` to the class, based on your
advice about what does and does not belong here.

In contrast, you've written a bunch of nice method and module
docstrings, thank you.

If a linter "made" you insert a docstring, then consider using
[a linter](https://pypi.org/project/ruff)
that is less picky by default,
or change your current linter's config.

---

## local variable vs object attribute

```
        self.path_config = path_config
```

Consider deleting that,
preferring a call to `self.load_config(path_config)`.

Consider renaming the parameter to `config_path`.

---

## extra helper

Usually I encourage folks to break up functions
using Extract Helper, and then break them up some more.
But you already have nice bite-sized pieces here.
Maybe `setup_additional_params` should be
merged with `load_config`?
Then the codify client and env wouldn't
go out of scope, so we could create them
as local variables, use them twice, and be done with them.

Consider renaming `setup_additional_params`
to `setup_runtime_params`, as an explanation
of why those params can't come from a static
text file.

---

## dict vs object attribute

```
        self.config["engine"] = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db)
```

Yeah, I agree with you, that is **not** a "config" item,
and it looks weird. Prefer:

```
        self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db)
```

BTW, I like that `db or ...` defaulting idiom.
However, I don't like the default empty string value,
as it is useless, it won't give us e.g. a sqlite in-memory database.
So I recommend eliding the default value.

---

## abbrev

```
    def setup_logging(self, fn_log: str = "default.log") -> None:
```

It wouldn't hurt to spell out `filename_log`
(or `log_filename`).

```
        path_log = Path(self.config["basepath"], "logs", fn_log)
```

This is perfectly fine as-is. Usual way to phrase this would be with `/` slashes:

```
        path_log = self.config["basepath"] / "logs" / fn_log)
```

---

This code achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have applied, almost, all of the improvements mentioned. The one thing I am unsure of is the last sentence of "clean import" section. Which method don't you see in the source?

Comment: By "clean import" I mean: no fatal error on missing env var, no chatty print() side effects, that sort of thing. The OP code calls load_dotenv(). It was my belief that `pip` would install a certain package. But when I visited the [linked](https://github.com/pedroburon/dotenv/blob/master/dotenv/__init__.py) package source code I was unable to locate load_dotenv(), so I couldn't tell what failure modes it might suffer from.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. The package is: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/